# How to use negative globs in Perl

Tags: shell, glob

/usr/bin/sec  --input=/var/log/remote/mail-today/*=FILEEVENT_MAIL

So i'm using an event correlator, in order to select the files for input. /var/log/remote/mail-today/* is the 'glob' string that allows for files to be selected.

But in this directory there are a number of files, i'd only like to select the non-tarred files:

file1.gz
file2.gz
file3.gz
file4
file5
file6

I was wondering whether it was possible to do a negative glob.

Comment: Globbing is something the Shell is doing and not Perl.

Comment: What does perl actually have to do with what you have shown?